# Client-Server AngularJS App - When should I update the model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mvvm, model, viewmodel

I'm working on a client-server application built with angularJS. For data exchanges I'm using HTML5 WebSockets. My server has a dataset that also exists as copy on my client. I refer to this as my model as here is all the raw data.

Via WebSockets I'm able to get/set those data. There may also be random data updates from the server (push).

I'm using different custom services/factories to provide a layer that allows all my modules to create data packets and send them to my server. They also provide wrapper for my model and may change the reprasentation of this data in the view (like timestamps converted to real time, etc.). I have different controllers that access those services to reach for functions or values.

I hope this describes my current architecture good enough. Now my question:

On data updates from the server I update my model data and then inform all modules that make use of this data with the new value. It's like:

```
Server -> Model -> ViewModel -> View
```

That works fine and I guess it's ok from the view of the MVVM pattern.

But I'm struggling a bit with publishing updates from the view. At the moment it's like:

```
View -> ViewModel -> Model (at first update the model)
            |
            -------> Server (after that send the data to the server)
```

So, when there's a user updating data in the view, the viewmodel gets updated via angulars data binding. Then the viewmodel calls a service to create an output packet that will be sent to the server. When the packets gets commited my model will be updated with the new data and the packet will be given over to my websocket connection, updating the data on the server.

**Is this the/one right way to do so? Is it ok to update my model even before the packet is sent to the server? Should I send the update to the server, wait for an OK and only then update the model?**

Comment: probably best to update server before updating page model. Allows opportunity to adjust if connection fails or for validation errors

Comment: I thought that, too. But there may also always be some time between user action, server-client-communication (request, response) and the final model update. I don't know if this could be critical on a bad internet connection.